# How do I get the dimensions of a WPF element at run-time without specifying them at compile-time

Tags: c#, wpf, size

The problem?

```
<UI:PanelBrowser Margin="12,27,12,32"></UI:PanelBrowser>
```

WPF is ridiculous in that not manually specifying properties (Such as Width and Height) in this case causes them to have the values `Doulbe.NaN`. The problem is that I need to know this number. I'm not going to manually set a width and height in the XAML because that stops it from resizing.

Given the above piece of XAML (this object is a simple subclass of the Border control), how can I get the values of the Width and Height properties at run-time?

Edit :

Wow, I feel ridiculous. I read about `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, but they were consistently returning 0 and 0 for me. The reason is that I was testing for these properties in the constructor of the Framework Element, before they were actually initialized. Hope this helps someone who runs into the same issue and testing fallacies. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the [FrameworkElement.ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) and [ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) properties, instead.

Answer (score 2):

The WPF FrameworkElement class provides two DependencyProperties for that purpose: `FrameworkElement.ActualWidth` and `FrameworkElement.ActualHeight` will get the rendered width and height at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use elements' `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties to get the values of the width and height when they were drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Use **VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(Visual Reference)**, and it return Rect.
Then Check the height of the Rect.
Ex)

```
Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(element);
double height = bounds.height;
```

**OR**
Use **UIElement.Measure(Size size)**, it will assign the Size into DesiredSize.
Ex)

```
myElement.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));  
double height = myElement.DesiredSize.Height;
```